# Gelfand pairs in $SO(p,q)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups

I am considering the groups $SO(p,q)$ over the reals. And inside it some parabolic subgroup, $P$. It can be the minimal parabolic but that is not the issue.
It is well known that $P$ has a Levi decomposition, $P=L \cdot U$ where L is Levi subgroup and U unipotent radical.

Here is my question:

is the pair $(SO(p,q), U)$ a Gelfand pair? The answer is likely to be no, this is due to the fact that $L$ is not commutative and we expect $(L,1)$ to be a Gelfand pair. I do like some stronger argument here.

This issue was suggested to be "solved" by introducing a character of $U$, named $X$ and asking if $\big(SO(p,q), U\cdot\operatorname{stab}(L,X)\big)$ is a $X$ twisted Gelfand pair.

Now with this problem i have a progress as $(L, \operatorname{stab}(L,X))$ is a Gelfand pair.
I want to suggest this to be some sort of a test to check if the pair is Gelfand or not. But with no progress.

Any help will be appreciated.

Side remarks:
This is part of my thesis for my Ph.d studies.
Joint work with Prof. Rami Aizenbhud, and Prof. Dimitry Gourevich.

Comment: "The issue was suggested to be "solved"" by whom?

Comment: by my advisers, which are mentioned in the question.